# JavaScript I want Change only part of the List element

Tags: javascript

```
var saveList = [].concat(caller.gridView01.getData("modified"));
        saveList = saveList.concat(caller.gridView01.getData("deleted"));
        saveList = saveList.concat(caller.gridView02.getData("deleted"));

        var test = caller.gridView02.getData("deleted");
         console.log("testList",test);
```

console.log("testList",test);

[image]

[image]

What I want is that the object is stored as an element in the list named test, but I want to change only a part of the object's interior. To be precise, `__deleted__: false`
I want to change to `true` and `__modified__: true` to `false` It is possible to delete or insert an element itself, but I don't know how to control the inside of the element! Is it possible?

Comment: Object.getOwnPropertyNames appears and I use console.log(test.length); I have verified that it is a list array with  and I'll change the question to be more specific

Comment: I tried to express __ in the stackoverflow text editor and it was highlighted, so it is difficult to write the exact value Can you forgive me?

Comment: Thanks, I changed it according to your suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, like this:

```
test[0].__modified__ = true;
test[0].__deleted__ = true;
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, I understand how to change the property value